# iframe not loading the html text

Tags: html, internet-explorer, iframe

I have a string variable. This string variable contains HTML content.

I want to use this string variable to load data in to iFRAME.

`iFRAME "SRCDOC"` property doesn't support IE.

Please any one help on this , how to load html content to iframe.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can write directly into IFRAME document.

Let's say you have an IFRAME:

```
<iframe id="bla"></iframe>
```

You can write code:

```
var ifr = document.getElementById("bla")
var doc = ifr.contentDocument || ifr.contentWindow.document;

var str = "<h1>Hello World!</h1>"

doc.open();
doc.write(str);
doc.close();
```

Ordinary it is not recommended to use `document.write`, but in this case it does the job.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/U6q7T/2/

Comment: thanks for quick reply. How to send string from code behind to js

Comment: @user3680114 that's a different question. You did not mention any ASP.NET in your original question. But you can have a hidden field - assign its value in code-behind and read it in JS code.